# Js inherited class instance undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I have a class which extends another class. But a function defined in the parent class that tries to reference "this", throws an exception stating "this" is undefined. Here is the relevant code:

```
class Entity {
    constructor() {
        this.axes = ['x', 'y'];
        ...

    updatePosition() {
        this.axes.forEach(function(axis) {
            this.position[axis] += this.velocity[axis];
        });
    }
}

class Player extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super();
        ....
    }
...
}

var player = new Player();
```

And the error thrown:

```
.../player.js:25
            this.position[axis] += this.velocity[axis];
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
```

Do you know why is the instance undefined, and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of `forEach` function `this` is global object not the player instance. Since you're using ES6 you could solve it by changing to arrow function like so:

```
updatePosition() {
    this.axes.forEach((axis) => {
        this.position[axis] += this.velocity[axis];
    });
}
```

Read more here, under "lexical this": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Or you could reference a `self` variable pointing to `this` above the forEach function, and inside the forEach use the `self` variable.

Comment: yeah, we all do ;)